# PHP function to determine in which file and line i set a variable

Tags: php, variables, constants

The title says it all. I just wonder if there is a PHP function that cam tell me in which file and which line i set my variable.

Comment: If you properly structured your code with small functions/methods, this question is not one you should ever be asking, because your variable scopes should be so small as to be traceable with the naked eye.

Comment: Perhaps [debug_backtrace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is unclear; specify what you want to achieve, how it should work, some example code, something you've tried, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use php magic constant

```
__FILE__  -- The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned. Since PHP 4.0.2, __FILE__ always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances.
__LINE__  -- The current line number of the file.
```

[LINK HERE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

**Enjoy :)**

---

Comment: This is not exactly what i wanted, but i guess it's the best answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

But that doesn't stop you from **creating your own**, using the function [token_get_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) together with the [list of all tokens](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)!

**This is how I would do it:**

```
/**
 * Where Are My Variables Assigned!?
 * @author Smuuf
 */
class WAMVA {

    public function scan($file, $allAssignments = false) {

        if (!is_file($file)) return false;

        // Get all tokens from the file and initialize result array
        $tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($file));
        $result = array();

        // Go through all tokens
        foreach ($tokens as $index => $token) {

            // Variable token ('$...')
            if (isset($token[0]) && $token[0] === T_VARIABLE){

                // Skip all whitespaces
                $add = 1;
                while (is_array($tokens[$index + $add]) && $tokens[$index + $add][0] === T_WHITESPACE) {
                    $add++;
                }

                // And if next token is an assigment operator, save the variable token
                if (self::isAssignment($tokens[$index + $add])) {

                    // Get all assignments? Or just the first present in the file?
                    if ($allAssignments) {
                        $result[] = array("variable" => substr($token[1], 1), "line" => $token[2]);
                    } else {
                        $key = substr($token[1], 1);
                        if (!isset($result[$key])) $result[$key] = $token[2];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;

    }

    protected function isAssignment($input) {

        if ($input == "=") {

            return true;

        } elseif (is_array($input)) {

            // http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php
            switch ($input[0]) {
                case T_AND_EQUAL:
                case T_CONCAT_EQUAL:
                case T_DIV_EQUAL:
                case T_MINUS_EQUAL:
                case T_MOD_EQUAL:
                case T_MUL_EQUAL:
                case T_OR_EQUAL:
                case T_PLUS_EQUAL:
                case T_SL_EQUAL:
                case T_SR_EQUAL:
                case T_XOR_EQUAL:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

`print_r(WAMVA::scan("./test.php", true));`

**Output ($allAssignments = false):**

```
Array
(
    [translation_array] => 11
    [target_language] => 12
    [lang_abbr] => 41
    [translated] => 47
)
```

**Output ($allAssignments = true):**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [variable] => translation_array
            [line] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [variable] => target_language
            [line] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [variable] => target_language
            [line] => 24
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [variable] => translation_array
            [line] => 25
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [variable] => lang_abbr
            [line] => 41
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [variable] => translated
            [line] => 47
        )

)
```

Comment: But that doesn't determine the file. Oh well, I was bored anyway.